# Escape \ a HTML form in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to put my forms in a single $variable, but i'm getting errors.

What is the proper format to put these forms in a single variable:

```
<form method="post" action="?pageid=C_beheer&amp;cmd=edit&id=<?php echo $events['ID']; ?>&month=<?php echo $month?>&day=<?php echo $day?>&year=<?php echo $year?>">
<input type="hidden" name="up_event_id" id="event_id" value="<?php echo $events['kalenderID']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="edit"  value="Edit">
</form>
```

**$formEdit = "posted code here";**

I know the all the " should be escaped by \ and remove the PHP closing/opening tags, but what do I need tot do with the $variables in the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$formEdit = "<form method=\"post\" action=\"?pageid=C_beheer&amp;cmd=edit&id=".$events['ID']."&month=".$month."&day=".$day."&year=".$year."\">";
```

Use `.` as the operator for string concatenations.
I left out your inputs and just used the opening form-tag as an example, but you may easily add the rest of the tags for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character does not have any special meaning in HTML. But you of course [don't have to escape stuff manually](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

You also have invalid HTML in the static part of the code:

```
cmd=edit&id=
        ^
```

You got it right in other parts:

```
?pageid=C_beheer&amp;cmd=edit
                ^^^^^
```

Comment: Very sharp;) I had have edited the code a couple times and did not post my backup here. Thanxs for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` and use the buffer to create the variable if you don't want to worry about escaping a bunch of HTML characters:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<form method="post" action="?pageid=C_beheer&amp;cmd=edit&id=<?php echo $events['ID']; ?>&month=<?php echo $month?>&day=<?php echo $day?>&year=<?php echo $year?>">
<input type="hidden" name="up_event_id" id="event_id" value="<?php echo $events['kalenderID']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="edit"  value="Edit">
</form>
<?php $form = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Essentially `ob_start()` turns output buffering on, and anything that is subsequently echoed is captured in the buffer.  `ob_get_clean()` both returns the content of the buffer and cleans it (basically just does both `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()`).

I like to use this method when I need to store large amounts of HTML in a variable.

Comment: Woah you just made my day, thank you for the help!